# Answer question with fewer than 30 characters, get the error, then extend the answer - captcha appears

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha

The minimum amount of characters per answer is 30 (wasn't it less, a while ago?). There are questions whose answer can safely be less than 30 chars, I've answered a few like that in the previous days (yes, the answers are sufficient. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545937/java-splitting-the-filename-into-a-base-and-extension/4545972#4545972). Without the links, the additional sentence and the "Take a look at", it's less than 30 chars, but still a good answer). Especially when answering from a mobile device, adding filling symbols like "Take a look at" rather than "Check" is not preferred.

So I provide such an answer, and get back the message that 30 characters are required. Then I extend the answer somehow, and submit again. And the Captcha appears.

It is annoying. And the captcha doesn't work on mobile. Can this check be disabled for users with, say, 1k+ reputation? Or at least the captcha be tested on mobile browsers (Android 2.2 default browser here)

Comment: `[Status-ByDesign]`. But I do agree that the whole sequence ending with a Captcha is irritating.

Comment: It used to be 15 about a week ago.

Comment: Take a look *at*

Comment: @marcog - of course :) fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Annoying,

<strike>Maybe we should do client side validation on length before initial submit ... I support that but "the boss" will have to approve.</strike>

I changed it so the captcha logic will only be triggered on submission of an actual question or answer. If the validation fails that does not count.

The 30 char limit has helped a huge amount with cutting down on [poor quality answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?page=1&pagesize=50&filter=all&customsort=shortest).

Comment: Wow, over 3000 pages of them already.  Cutting down?

Comment: @Hans ... that is all the old cruft ... I need to go through and do some serious batch deleting ...

Comment: no, client side validation was in before and removed because it became a nightmare to troubleshoot and keep the server and client in sync. Instead, we need to make it so failed post submissions aren't considered valid for the purpose of CAPTCHA tracking.. so you can keep clicking "submit" 50 times on a post of 15 chars and never get a captcha, ever.

Comment: @Jeff: finally! This is what it should have always done.. I assumed the old system was intended, for some weird reason.

Comment: I just tried to edit an old short answer on SO. Even with the link I added, it's still under 30 characters: http://imgur.com/ziE3sAD

Comment: @DrewDara-Abrams padding with HTML comments works: `<!-- this gibberish won't show up in a post -->`